# Catch git push --upstream output

Tags: git, terminal

I want to catch the output when I do:
`git push --set-upstream ...`

1 of the outputs is:
`remote:   https://...`

How can I grep (or something) from that output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git push | grep remote
```

The pipe character redirects the standard output of git to the standard input of grep.

Also, you could redirect the entire output to a file:

```
git push > out.txt
```

Redirection docs: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html
Pipe docs: http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-4.html

Comment: `git push | grep remote` isn't working for me..
I'm now creating the output to a file and then grep it from the file.
Thanks!